# Rate of convergence of Fourier series: Fourier sums vs their Cesàro means.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis, rate-of-convergence

Let $1<p<\infty$ and $f \in L^p(\mathbb{T})$. It is known that both Fourier sums of $f$ and Cesàro sums of the Fourier sums of $f$ converges in $L^p(\mathbb{T})$ to $f$, i.e.:
\begin{align*}
\bigg\|\sum_{k=-N}^N \hat{f}(k) e_k-f\bigg\|_p &\to 0, N\to\infty \\
\bigg\|\frac{1}{N+1}\sum_{n=0}^N\sum_{k=-n}^n \hat{f}(k) e_k-f\bigg\|_p &\to 0, N\to\infty
\end{align*}
where $\hat{f}$ is the (discrete) Fourier transform of $f$ and $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} = (t\mapsto e^{int})_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is the Fourier base.

> I'm wondering if we can somehow guarantee that the first or the second sum has better convergence rate under suitable conditions of regularity.

It follows an example of what I have in mind. Suppose that $f \in C^1(\mathbb{T})$. Let $(F_N)_{N\in\mathbb{N}}$ be the [Fejér kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel) and for $t\in \mathbb{T}$ let $\tau_t(f) = x\mapsto f(x-t)$. If $\delta >0$ we have that:
\begin{align*}
\bigg\|\frac{1}{N+1}\sum_{n=0}^N\sum_{k=-n}^n \hat{f}(k) e_k-f\bigg\|_p &=\|F_N*f-f\|_p \\
&\le \sup_{t\in[-\delta,\delta]}\|\tau_t(f)-f\|_p + \frac{\|f\|_p}{\pi N}\Big(\frac{\sin(N\delta/2)}{\sin(\delta/2)}\Big)^2 \\
&\le \|f'\|_\infty\delta + \frac{\|f\|_p}{\pi N}\Big(\frac{1}{\sin(\delta/2)}\Big)^2
\end{align*}
Then, if we choose $\delta = \delta_N = N^{-1/3}$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
\bigg\|\frac{1}{N+1}\sum_{n=0}^N\sum_{k=-n}^n \hat{f}(k) e_k-f\bigg\|_p &\le \|f'\|_\infty N^{-1/3} + \frac{\|f\|_p}{\pi N}\Big(\frac{1}{\sin(1/(2N^{1/3}))}\Big)^2 \\
&\le C N^{-1/3}
\end{align*}
On the other hand, if we also suppose that $1\le p\le 2$ then
\begin{align*}
\bigg\|\sum_{k=-N}^N \hat{f}(k) e_k-f\bigg\|_p &\le \bigg\|\sum_{k=-N}^N \hat{f}(k) e_k-f\bigg\|_2 = \bigg\|\sum_{|k|\ge N+1} \hat{f}(k) e_k\bigg\|_2 \\ &= \bigg(\sum_{|k|\ge N+1} |\hat{f}(k)|^2\bigg)^{1/2}
\le \frac{1}{N+1} \bigg(\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} n^2 |\hat{f}(k)|^2\bigg)^{1/2} \\
&\le \tilde{C}N^{-1}. 
\end{align*}
So, if $f \in C^1(\mathbb{T})$ and $1\le p \le 2$ we somehow manage to get a better estimate for the rate of convergence of the Fourier sums of $f$ than the one we got for the Cesàro means. However, I don't know if these estimates are sharp in any sense and if $p>2$ I don't know how to treat the Fourier sums. So:

> Are this estimates sharp in any sense? (i.e. can we do better than this under the stated conditions or there are functions that realize these bounds?) What about the case $p>2$? Are there other techniques to get estimates like these? Where can I find something in this sense in the literature?